# WindowsのAnacondaPrompt環境でSpeechRecognitionを使用する方法

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, audio

以下の記事を参考にさせて頂いてGoogleの音声入力機能をPythonで使用したいと考えています。
https://qiita.com/daiarg/items/ff1b9f91d0804e6a8f18

pipでSpeechRecognitionは問題なくインストールでました。

```
pip install SpeechRecognition
```

しかし、pyaudioをインストールする部分

```
#マイクロホンからの入力に必要
$ sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev
$ sudo apt-get install python-pyaudio python3-pyaudio
$ pip install pyaudio
```

がエラーでインストールできなかったため、pyaudioは[別の方法](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283840/i-cant-install-pyaudio-on-windows-how-to-solve-error-microsoft-visual-c-14)でインストールをしました。

```
pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

ここで

```
$ python -m speech_recognition
```

を実行すると、Windowsインストーラーが起動し、ずっと進捗がないままインストーラーが消えません。30分くらい放置していたのですが、反応がないためタスクマネージャーから強制終了させました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このようにWindowsインストーラーが起動して止まってしまうのは、Anaconda Promptの問題なのか、マイクの問題なのか、Windowsの問題なのかなどが分りません。

どうすればSpeechRecognitionをWindowsのAnaconda Prompt環境で使用できるようになりますでしょうか？

【私の実行環境】
Windows10 64bit
Python3.7.4
AnacondaPrompt(Anaconda3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SpeechRecognition`を`pip`でインストールしたからそういう状況が発生した、という可能性があります。以下を試してみてください。(当方では2.の環境・手順で出来ています)

1. Anaconda Prompt環境を継続する

   - いったん`pip uninstall SpeechRecognition`でアンインストールする
   - 次に`conda install -c conda-forge SpeechRecognition`で`conda-forge`から`SpeechRecognition`をインストールする
   - マイク・スピーカーが接続されていて使える状態であることを確認する
   - `python -m speech_recognition`を実行してみる
2. 新規に環境を作成する

   - `ANACONDA NAVIGATOR`の`Environments`で`Create`で新規にPython環境を作成する
   - 作った環境で`Not installed`を選び、`Channels`に`conda-forge`を追加する
   - `Search Packages`に`SpeechRecognition`を入力し、リストに出てきた`SpeechRecognition`をインストールする
   - 作った環境の`▶`で`Open Terminal`を選択し、`pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`を行う
   - マイク・スピーカーが接続されていて使える状態であることを確認する
   - 作った環境の`▶`の`Open Terminal`で`python -m speech_recognition`を実行してみる

あるいは`Anaconda3`がすべてのユーザーを対象にインストールされているとか？
上記両方とも駄目で`Anaconda3`がすべてのユーザーでインストールされているなら、このユーザーのみでインストールし直して上記を試してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。手順１と2を試してみましたが、やはりWindowsインストーラーが起動して次に進みませんでした。Anaconda3は「Just me(このユーザーのみ)」でインストールしております。別の方法を探してみようと思います

Comment: 起動しているWindowsインストーラーは何のプログラムなのでしょう？そうしたものを調べるとか、既にあるものならいったん削除なりアンインストールしておいてみるとかはどうでしょう？

Comment: インストーラーの画面の切り替わりが速すぎて何のインストーラーかよく分からなかったのですが、画面を動画で録画した後にコマ送りで確認したところ、使用している記憶のないYamaha製のUSBドライバーだったようです。これをアンインストールしたところ無事SpeechRecognitionが動作しました。ありがとうございました!